# Functions between products

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, terminology

Is there a specific name for a function $f:A\times B\rightarrow C\times D$, s.t. the following conditions hold:

1. $\text{pr}_2 f(a,b)=\text{pr}_2 f(a,b')$ for all $a\in A$ and $b,b'\in B$
2. $\text{pr}_1 f(a,b)=\text{pr}_1 f(a',b)$ for all $a,a'\in A$ and $b\in B$

Here, $\text{pr}$ means "projection". What if we use $\text{pr}_1$ instead of $\text{pr}_2$ in 1, and $\text{pr}_2$ instead of $\text{pr}_1$ in 2?

Are there some interesting examples of such functions in algebra, and what's their categorial meaning?